# Convert dict string to list of dictionary to insert to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary

I have  string data (dict_string) as below not separated by comma or anything but each line ends with \n :

```
data = {"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109897,"Title":"Prop 1","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? // ","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"}\n
       {"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109890,"Title":"Prop 2","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? //","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"}\n
```

i want to convert this to list of dictionary  as :

```
[{"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109897,"Title":"Prop 1","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? // ","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"},
{"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109890,"Title":"Prop 2","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? //","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"}]
```

so that I can insert this to mongodb.

I tried replace and then split  as below

```
data = data.replace("\n{", "|{")
data = data.split("|")
```

but this generates list of string ends with \n something  like this : ['{}', '{}'..., \n]

Eval throws string literal errors.

How do I achieve this ?  By any chance can i use json loads or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost got the answer, you could do this by having a check for line and replacing the "\n", good luck.

```
import ast
data = data.replace("\n{", "|{")
[ast.literal_eval(line.replace("\n", " ")) for line in data.split("|") if line]
```

Comment: happy to help, i dint have to say much, you were so close :)

Comment: I have another question regex is better or  replace with eval is better in performance. Because its a millions of data. or both same ?

Comment: for simple thing like this i think replace is better, refer http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2007/02/judicial-use-of-regex.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex with `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast

data = '''{"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109897,"Title":"Prop 1","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? // ","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"}
       {"Date1":"2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","peerval":"222.22000","PID":109890,"Title":"Prop 2","Temp":5,"Temp Actual":5,"Temp Predicted":3.9,"Level":"Medium","Explaination":"Source: Some title data might me data \n  some link http:\\www.ggogle\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? //","creator":"\\etc\\someid","createdtime" :"2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z"}'''

for i in re.findall(r"\{.*?\}", data.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''), flags=re.DOTALL):
    print(ast.literal_eval(i))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Date1': '2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z', 'Temp Predicted': 3.9, 'Temp': 5, 'Title': 'Prop 1', 'Level': 'Medium', 'PID': 109897, 'createdtime': '2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z', 'Temp Actual': 5, 'Explaination': 'Source: Some title data might me data   some link http:\\www.ggogle\\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? // ', 'creator': '\\etc\\someid', 'peerval': '222.22000'}
{'Date1': '2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z', 'Temp Predicted': 3.9, 'Temp': 5, 'Title': 'Prop 2', 'Level': 'Medium', 'PID': 109890, 'createdtime': '2017-02-12T15:24:38.380Z', 'Temp Actual': 5, 'Explaination': 'Source: Some title data might me data   some link http:\\www.ggogle\\.com with some sepcial characters >< ? //', 'creator': '\\etc\\someid', 'peerval': '222.22000'}
```

---

or

```
print([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in re.findall(r"\{.*?\}", data.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''), flags=re.DOTALL)])
```

Comment: how do i convert it to list of dictionary

Comment: The second snippet should give you a list of dict.. `print([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in re.findall(r"\{.*?\}", data.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''), flags=re.DOTALL)])`

Comment: I have another question regex is better or  replace with eval is better in performance. Because its a millions of data.